# Using DirectX 11 in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, directx, directx-11

I am trying to use DirectX 11 in my C++ project but when I compile I get an error saying:

```
D3D11 ERROR: D3D11 header version mismatch.
The application was compiled against and will only work with D3D11_SDK_VERSION (1), but the currently installed runtime is version (7).
Recompile the application against the appropriate SDK for the installed runtime.
```

I have no idea what is causing this. Is there a way to switch which runtime it is trying to compile for? I installed the DirectX SDK from June 2010. I tried to follow Microsofts directions here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx) to ensure things were setup correctly for using DirectX. I still get this error though. Does anyone have any idea of what may be causing this and how to fix it? I'm using Windows 8 64-bit and Visual Studio 2012.

**For Reference**

I started this as an empty C++ solution, not as a DirectX application. Here are the portions of my code which deal with DirectX

```
#include <amp.h>
#include <amp_math.h>
#include <amp_graphics.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <dxgi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11")
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi")

// Inside main()
    IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter = nullptr; // Use default adapter

    unsigned int createDeviceFlags = D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DISABLE_GPU_TIMEOUT;
    ID3D11Device *pDevice = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *pContext = nullptr;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(pAdapter,
                                    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN,
                                    NULL,
                                    createDeviceFlags,
                                    NULL,
                                    0,
                                    D3D11_SDK_LAYERS_VERSION,
                                    &pDevice,
                                    &featureLevel,
                                    &pContext);
    if(FAILED(hr) ||
        ((featureLevel != D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1) &&
        (featureLevel != D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0)))
    {
        std::wcerr << "Failed to create Direct3D 11 device" << std::endl;
        return 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In place of `D3D11_SDK_LAYERS_VERSION` you need to use `D3D11_SDK_VERSION` as documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476082.aspx).